# How do I convert string to JSON and convert back?

Tags: java, ruby, json

I need to convert "pretty" JSON to compact format, so I followed these steps:

1. Read the "pretty" JSON from a file.
2. `temp = JSON.parse(json_string)`
3. `jsonstring = temp.to_s`

when I parse `json_string` it throws 
`unexpected token`.

This is the "pretty" version:

```
{
   "key1" : "value1",
   "key2" : "value2"
}
```

And the version after compact:

```
{"key1"=>"value1","key2"=>"value2"}
```

When I write in Java, I could parse JSON with `:,=>` delimiters. But Ruby doesn't accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `jsonstring = temp.to_json`, rather than `jsonstring = temp.to_s`, which converts a hash to string, not JSON encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's JSON allows you to write:

```
JSON[JSON[json_string]]
```

That is equivalent to:

```
(JSON.parse(json_string)).to_json
```

In the first example, JSON looks at the class of the parameter, and sees if it's a string, and, if so, parses it into a Ruby hash. Then the outer JSON checks its parameter, sees it's a hash and turns it back into a JSON string. See [`JSON[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-c-5B-5D) for more information.

```
require 'json'

str = '{
   "key1" : "value1",
   "key2" : "value2"
}'

puts str
# >> {
# >>    "key1" : "value1",
# >>    "key2" : "value2"
# >> }

JSON[str] # => {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}

puts JSON[JSON[str]]
# >> {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```